# Webscraping Selenium with Python : Unable to click a link that has javascript calling a function wrapped in a href tag

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, web-scraping

Problem Statement: I am trying to scrape data by navigating across the various links on a website until I reach the below piece of code corresponding to a hypertext reference pointing to "Patient List".

```
<td height="20" align="middle" nowrap="">
<a href="javascript:goPatientList()"><b>Patient List</b></a>
</td>
```

I copied the xpath of the hypertext reference as shown below in the code.

---

The below section has my python code.

```
import selenium

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://example.com")

print(driver.title)



username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')

username.send_keys("username")

password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")

password.send_keys("password")

driver.find_element_by_name("Login").click()


driver.find_element_by_id("tab5").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("menu5_3").click()

**driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/a").click()**
```

---

Error that I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "login.py", line 31, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/a").click()

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 295, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 756, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_responseraise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455517 (2c6d2707d8ea850c862f04ac066724273981e88f),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
```

---

Can someone review the piece of code and guide me in this process ?

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchElementException` means selenium couldn't find the element. Most probably the xpath that you are using is wrong. Check your xpath. You can also test your xpath such as with Firefox firebug extension.

Another possibility is selenium is fast when we compare to a human. when selenium loads the page and click maybe there is no button or relate javascript.So we can tell the selenium to wait a little bit then click. So add wait function before your click.

```
driver.find_element_by_name("Login").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Comment: Hell Harun .. Thank you for your reply. I did try the firefox firebug and I get the same xpath.

Answer (score 0):

you need to learn how to make proper xpaths. Firebugs are not the best possible most of the time

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Thanks Felix . I will refer that document and try to understand the usage of the xpath.